# regex is not is not matching value in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying matching number value in a list and regex is working fine on Jenkins script console but when I use the same code in the pipeline my code it returns match as false

```
def tag = ["fork-point", "fork-3.0.1", "fork-3.0.0", "2.0.2", "2.0.1", "2.0.0", "1.0.1", "1.0.0"]

List<String> extractSubListUsingRegex( List<String> l) {

    String regex = "^(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[1-9]\\d*)"
    List<String> subList = []
    for (String tag in l) {
        println tag
        boolean isMatching = (tag ==~regex)
        if (isMatching == true){
            subList.add(tag)
        }
    }

    return subList
}
println extractSubListUsingRegex(tag)
```

Here is the regex
https://regex101.com/r/BvqB6e/1

Comment: Couple of possible issues here: `==~` operator is a restrictive exact match, and the RHS argument for the `==~` operator should be an object type somewhere in the regular expression class family, and probably not a string. Try changing the operator to `=~` and/or the RHS to `/^(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[1-9]\\d*)/`.

Comment: Thanks, @MattSchuchard, the parameter value was a string and was able to fix it by changing the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was regex was looking for non string value but the parameter output value was a string and hence failing.